# How do I force a Chrome Packaged App to print when the developer has disabled this feature?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, postman, google-chrome-app

How do I force a Chrome Packaged App to print when the developer has disabled this feature?

The particular application I am trying to print from is the Postman Packaged App. I want to print out the result of an API test. The print shortcut key (Command-P on OSX) does not work, nor does right clicking in the application. These all appear to have been disabled by the developer.

Edit: You can start Chrome with the --debug-packed-apps which grants access to the developer console, but that doesn't seem to help very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't print a Chrome App window any more than you can print a native app window. It doesn't really make sense. You can take a screenshot of the application window and print that. I suggest requesting that the application developer add print functionality to their app as that will likely produce a more nicely formatted result than forcing the app's layout through the printer.

Comment: A Chrome App is nothing more than a website living in a Chrome Browser Window, is it not? I'm not asking for the "Google Approved" method of doing this. I'm asking for a way to invoke a print() method on the currently displayed document. Consider for a moment that these are not natively rendered elements on the host platform, but web elements rendered on an HTML canvas. (Note: the Postman Packaged App uses Twitter Bootstrap!) By comparison, there are ways to do this using the Post Script / Portable Document Format backing layers in Cocoa on OS X to print a PDF of anything on the screen.